# Joomla 3 XML Feed Via FTP

Tags: joomla-3.x, xml

I am looking for some advice on the best way to pull down an xml file off an ftp address and display the content in an article or module.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-expert-agent-xml-feed/ is exactly what I'm after for Joomla. It is for displaying houses/properties.

From initial research, I'm not finding anything that does this for Joomla, I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know any PHP?  You could probably take a feed feeder and then add the authentication to the cURL request.

Comment: I don't YellowWebMonkey unfortunately. Is there nothing in Joomla that can already do this? Thanks

Comment: I actually want to do this too.  Do you have access to Agent Expert?  Reading an XML file is not an issue, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't need FTP.

Comment: If you're still interested perhaps contact me via my Twitter https://twitter.com/ImSquareBalloon

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any extension that out of the box will authenticate to get the feed.  
Joomla Works makes a solid feed reader (https://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/simple-rss-feed-reader). 
 You might contact them to see if they could add the feature.
You could also try customizing the helper.php file in it include a cURL authentication similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl/20064360.  However, that would depend on how the FTP is configured and whether it would even accept that kind of request.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas YellowWebMonkey, I will have to pass on this information to see what can be done as this is out of my skillset.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of the file that you would find most relevant.  It is contained in 
**/inc/admin/views/class-admin.php**

```
  public function download_xml( $remote_file, $remote_user, $remote_pass )  {
    // Continue if FTP extension exists on the PHP server
    if(function_exists('ftp_connect')) {
      //#STEP 1 - Connect to FTP

      $ftp_host = 'ftp.expertagent.co.uk'; // this is constant
      $ftp_port = 21; // this is constant
      $ftp_timeout = 10; // 10 seconds timeout
      $ftp_username = $remote_user;
      $ftp_password = $remote_pass;

      $file = $remote_file;
      $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // gotta be 'xml'
      $filename = basename($file, '.xml');

      // make sure it's XML since that's what we do!
      if( $extension !== 'xml' ) {
        update_option( 'fse_wpeaxf_remote_file', '' );
        exit( __( 'File does not exist. Please specify an XML file.', $this->plugin_name ) . ' <a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page='. $this->plugin_name ) . '">' . __( 'Go back', $this->plugin_name ) . '</a>.' );
      }

      //#STEP 2 - Download File
      $ftp_connection = ftp_connect( $ftp_host, $ftp_port, $ftp_timeout );
      if( !$ftp_connection ) {
        exit( __( 'Could not connect to FTP at the moment. Please check your FTP server status and try again.', $this->plugin_name ) . ' <br />' . __( 'If unsure, please contact Expert Agent at', $this->plugin_name ) . ' support@expertagent.co.uk <a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page='. $this->plugin_name ) . '">' . __( 'Go back', $this->plugin_name ) . '</a>' );
      }

      $login_result = ftp_login( $ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_password );
      if( !$login_result ) {
        exit( __( 'Login details did not match. Please check your FTP login details and try again.', $this->plugin_name ) . ' <a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page='. $this->plugin_name ) . '">' . __( 'Go back', $this->plugin_name ) . '</a>' );
      }

      $plugin_basename = explode( "/", plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 2 )[0]; // get the plugin's directory name  // need to change

      // $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); // Array of key => value pairs // don't need
      $plugin_upload_dir = JURI::root() . 'media/' . $plugin_basename . '/';
      $plugin_upload_dir_xml = JURI::root() . 'media/' . $plugin_basename . '/xml/';

      // Create Directory /media/plugin_name/
      if(!file_exists( $plugin_upload_dir )) {
        mkdir( $plugin_upload_dir, 0755, true );
      }

      // Create Directory /media/plugin_name/xml/
      if(!file_exists( $plugin_upload_dir_xml )) {
        mkdir( $plugin_upload_dir_xml, 0755, true );
      }

      $local_file_path = $plugin_upload_dir_xml . $file;
      $server_file_path = $file;

      ftp_pasv( $ftp_connection, true ); // So we don't get a BINARY Warning...
      ftp_get( $ftp_connection, $local_file_path, $server_file_path, FTP_BINARY );
      ftp_close( $ftp_connection );

    } else {

      exit( __( 'Please enable FTP on your server before proceeding.', $this->plugin_name ) . ' <a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page='. $this->plugin_name ) . '">' . __( 'Go back', $this->plugin_name ) . '</a>' );

    }
  }
```

In Joomla! you would need to change some parts, I made an extremely rough start on this but I'll probably create this as a commercial extension in time.